# Java Date Parsing - How to parse dates with Tues?

Tags: java, date, parsing

I'm trying to parse few dates where the day of the week is not in the regular pattern like Tue or Tuesday, instead it is Tues. Does anyone happen to know how to parse these dates?

`Tues, 11 Mar 2008 00:00:00 PST`
`Thurs, 30 March 2015 09:00:00 PST` 
The following doesn't work since there are four characters in Tues

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z");
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does it follow Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun ? @swetha

Comment: Why is it "Tues"? Reaplce it with `String#replace()` and then parse it.

Answer (score 3):

Found another way to solve this - using a custom DateFormatSymbols class

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("en", "US"));

// define custom short weekdays
String[] customShortWeekdays = {"", "Sun", "Mon","Tues", "Wed", "Thurs","Fri", "Sat"};
symbols.setShortWeekdays(customShortWeekdays);

//parse date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", symbols);
newDate = sdf.parse(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String replacedDate = yourdate.toString().replace("Tues", "Tue"); //or
String replacedDate = yourdate.toString().replace("Thurs", "Thur"); 
//Convert back to a date if necessary
```

This [Replace Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) allows you to have a format that actually works with your `EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z` format.

Edit: I see that @Tom posted this in the comments while I was working on this. So credit to @Tom for posting the comment prior to my answer being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip over that part. The day/month/year are sufficient.